# recorrer array php

Tags: php, array

estoy trabajando con php generando el ingreso de una orden de trabajo, en mi vista tengo los datos principales (cliente, fecha, etc) ademas lleno una tabla html para que visualmente se vea que se está cargando,  pero a mi controlador envio, (además de datos principales), un array con los detalles trabajos recibidos, y dependiendo como arme un input hidden recibo lo siguiente:
soy muy malo trabajndo con array, por lo mismo no se me ocurre forma de hacerlo o generar el input que sea facil de trabajar.Gracias

```
    $item =$_POST['item'];
    $items = [];
    array_push($items, $item);
(
    [0] => producto=>129,paciente=>1,cantidad=>2,precio=>10530.00,subtotal=>21060
    [1] => producto=>128,paciente=>1,cantidad=>1,precio=>9436.50,subtotal=>9436.5
    [2] => producto=>132,paciente=>1,cantidad=>3,precio=>10395.00,subtotal=>31185
)
```

pero no puedo recorrer esto para ingresar un registro en tabla por cada item, he tratado entre otroas cosas con

```
  foreach($items as $posicion=>$campo) {
    echo  $posicion . " es " . $campo;
      echo "<br>";
  }
```

el input por fila de la tabla:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="producto=>129,paciente=>1,cantidad=>2,precio=>10395.00,subtotal=>21060">
```

Mi formulario:

```
      <div class="col-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Producto</th>
                      <th scope="col">Paciente</th>
                      <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                      <th scope="col">Acción</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>  
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td scope="col">
                      <select class="form-select select2" id="producto_id" name="producto_id" style="width:100%" lang="es">
                        <option value="--">--- Buscar Producto ---</option>
                          <?php
                            $datos_producto=$ins_login->datos_tabla("Normal","producto WHERE estado='Habilitado'","id,nombre,precio",0);
                          
                              while($campos_productos=$datos_producto->fetch()){
                                echo '<option value="'.$campos_productos['id'].'">'.$campos_productos['nombre'] .'-'.$campos_productos['precio'].'</option>';
                           
                          }?>
                      </select>

                      </td>
                      <td scope="col">
                      <select class="form-select select2" id="paciente_id" name="paciente_id" style="width:100%" lang="es">
                        <option value="--">--- Buscar Paciente ---</option>
                          <?php
                            $datos_paciente=$ins_login->datos_tabla("Normal","paciente ","id,dni,nombre, apellido",0);
                            
                              while($campos_paciente=$datos_paciente->fetch()){
                                echo '<option value="'.$campos_paciente['id'].'">'  .$campos_paciente['dni']. '-' .$campos_paciente['nombre']. ' ' .$campos_paciente['apellido'].'.</option>';
                            
                          }?>
                      </select>
                      </td>
                      <td scope="col">
                         <input type="number" class="form-control" name="cantidad_t" step="any" id="cantidad" style="width:100%" maxlength="10" required>
                      </td>
                      <td scope="col">
                        <button class="btn btn-info" id="add_item"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Agregar</button>
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>  
              </table>  
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12">
           <h5 class="card-title"><strong>Detalle Trabajo a Realizar:</strong></h5>
           <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-striped" id="detalle_trabajos">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Producto</th>
                    <th scope="col">Paciente</th>
                    <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                    <th scope="col">Precio</th>
                    <th scope="col">Total</th>                    
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
               
                </tbody>
              </table>          
            </div>
      
        </div>
```

mi funcion:

```
 $("#add_item").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    let filas = $('#detalle_trabajos').find('tbody tr').length;
    filas=filas++
    var array_producto = $('select[name="producto_id"] option:selected').text().split('-');
    var array_paciente = $('select[name="paciente_id"] option:selected').text().split('-');
    var producto=array_producto[1];
    var paciente=array_paciente[0];

    var htmlTags = '<tr>'+
        '<td>' + filas + '</td>'+
        '<td>' + array_producto[0] + '<input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="producto=>'+ $('select[name="producto_id"] option:selected').val() +',paciente=>'+ $('select[name="paciente_id"] option:selected').val() +',cantidad=>'+$('#cantidad').val() +',precio=>'+ array_producto[1] +',subtotal=>'+$('#cantidad').val()*array_producto[1] +'"></td>'+
        '<td>' +array_paciente[1] + '</td>'+
        '<td>' + $('#cantidad').val() + '</td>'+
        '<td>' + array_producto[1] + '</td>'+
        '<td>' + $('#cantidad').val()*array_producto[1] + '</td>'+
      '</tr>';
      
    $('#detalle_trabajos tbody').append(htmlTags);
    $('#cantidad').val(0);
    $('#paciente_id').prop('selectedIndex',-1);
    $('#producto_id').prop('selectedIndex',-1);

    

  });
```

Comment: yo lo que veo ahi es que tienes un primer item que contiene una cadena, y como valor de esa cadena tienes "producto=>129, paciente=>1..." Eso es una cadena, no un array... Puedes hacer un `print_r($item);` y mostrarnos que es lo que te llega al php?

Comment: @Jakala esto me resulta de print_r($item); Array
(
    [0] => producto=>129,paciente=>1,cantidad=>2,precio=>10530.00,subtotal=>21060
    [1] => producto=>128,paciente=>1,cantidad=>1,precio=>9436.50,subtotal=>9436.5
    [2] => producto=>132,paciente=>1,cantidad=>3,precio=>10395.00,subtotal=>31185
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que el problema que se plantea es como construir un array, desde la parte de front (html) para que, al recibirlo luego en php se pueda recorrer con cada uno de los elementos.

para ello, lo mas "comodo" parece ser utilizar varios campos hidden en tu codigo, separando la linea:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="producto=>129,paciente=>1,cantidad=>2,precio=>10395.00,subtotal=>21060">
```

En varias lineas hidden, de la manera siguiente:

```
un primer valor:
<input type="hidden" name="item[1][producto]"  value="129" />
<input type="hidden" name="item[1][paciente]"  value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="item[1][cantidad]"  value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="item[1][precio]"  value="10395.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="item[1][subtotal]"  value="21060" />

otro valor:
<input type="hidden" name="item[2][producto]"  value="129" />
<input type="hidden" name="item[2][paciente]"  value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="item[2][cantidad]"  value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="item[2][precio]"    value="10395.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="item[2][subtotal]"  value="21060" />
```

de esta manera, cuando llegan a php, en el $_POST['item'] tienes un array, que muestra dos elementos:

```
$_POST['item'] = [
  "1" => [
      "producto" => "129",
      "paciente" => "1",
      "cantidad" => "2",
      "precio" => "10395.00",
      "subtotal" => "21060"
  ],
  "2" => [
      "producto" => "129",
      "paciente" => "1",
      "cantidad" => "2",
      "precio" => "10395.00",
      "subtotal" => "21060"
  ],
]
```

NOTA: en algunos sitios te indican que no hace falta iniciar el primer indice [1] de cada elemento del array, ya que cada vez que se repite la segunda clave se entiende que es de un elemento nuevo. En teoria se puede hacer asi tambien:

```
un primer valor:
<input type="hidden" name="item[][producto]"  value="129" />
<input type="hidden" name="item[][paciente]"  value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="item[][cantidad]"  value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="item[][precio]"  value="10395.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="item[][subtotal]"  value="21060" />

otro valor:
<input type="hidden" name="item[][producto]"  value="129" />
<input type="hidden" name="item[][paciente]"  value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="item[][cantidad]"  value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="item[][precio]"    value="10395.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="item[][subtotal]"  value="21060" />
```

Analiza esto y mira si puede servirte para tu proposito.

Comment: muchas gracias si ese es mi problema, algo parecido tenia en un principio, ya lo pruebo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes esto en `$items`:

```
$items=array(
           array( 'producto'=>129,'paciente'=>1,'cantidad'=>2,'precio'=>10530.00,'subtotal'=>21060),
           array( 'producto'=>128,'paciente'=>1,'cantidad'=>1,'precio'=>9436.50,'subtotal'=>9436.5),
           array( 'producto'=>132,'paciente'=>1,'cantidad'=>3,'precio'=>10395.00,'subtotal'=>31185),
        );
```

Estamos hablando de un array asociativo, y puedes leerlo dentro de un bucle interno.

Por ejemplo:

```
  foreach($items as $item) {
      foreach ($item as $k=>$v) {
          echo "$k: $v".PHP_EOL;
      }
      echo "<hr />".PHP_EOL;
  }
```

**Salida:**

```
producto: 129
paciente: 1
cantidad: 2
precio: 10530
subtotal: 21060
<hr />
producto: 128
paciente: 1
cantidad: 1
precio: 9436.5
subtotal: 9436.5
<hr />
producto: 132
paciente: 1
cantidad: 3
precio: 10395
subtotal: 31185
<hr />
```

Comment: @a-cedano es justamente esto lo que necesito, pero no logro tu resultado `         //post   
            $usuario = MainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_id']);
            $fecha_r = MainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['fecha_r']);
            $fecha_e = MainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['fecha_e']);
            $obs = MainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['obs']);
            $item =$_POST['item'];
            //arrays
           $items = [];

            array_push($items, $item);
      
           `

Comment: @OcielGarrido no te entiendo muy bien. ¿Quieres construir una estructura así desde un formulario? ¿Qué elementos tiene ese formulario? ¿Cómo llenas los datos del mismo? ¿De dónde sacas esos datos?

Comment: @a-cedano si, lo que recibo en print_r($_POST['item'], es lo siguiente ` Array
(
    [0] => producto=>129,paciente=>1,cantidad=>2,precio=>10530.00,subtotal=>21060
    [1] => producto=>128,paciente=>1,cantidad=>1,precio=>9436.50,subtotal=>9436.5
    [2] => producto=>132,paciente=>1,cantidad=>3,precio=>10395.00,subtotal=>31185
)`

Comment: Poco importa lo que recibas en algo que quizá está mal, @OcielGarrido, aquí lo más importante es que nos expliques cómo construyes el formulario y de dónde sacas los datos. Hay mil maneras de crear una estructura ordenada, pero ni no sabemos de dónde obtienes los datos, cómo vienen organizados, etc, no podremos ayudarte de la mejor manera. Por ejemplo, en Javascript puedes usar atributos data- para poner en cada elemento un objeto completo y luego trabajarlo como array de objetos en PHP.

Comment: tanto los productos, como los pacientes, los cargo en un select dos los elementos que tiene son producto, paciente y cantidad, de ahí con jquery lleno la tabla html con paciente y demas y el input ocuelto con los datos

Comment: Tu problema entonces no es en PHP @OcielGarrido, mi respuesta te muestra lo fácil que es leer un array bien organizado. Aquí la cuestión es **cómo construir un array así** ¿? Eso debes hacerlo del lado del cliente, cuando creas el formulario y, como te dije antes, hay mil formas de hacer eso. Creo que estás enfocando mal el problema, creyendo que es un problema de PHP, no lo es, es un problema que viene del modo en que estás montando tus datos en el cliente (HTML/Javascript).

Comment: @acedano, gracias, creo que mi problema pasa por ahí, aprender a construir un buen array para poder manejarlo facilmente desde php,

Comment: Muchas gracias, con la ayuda de @a-cedano y jakala , obtuve lo que necesitaba

Comment: @OcielGarrido me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Saludos.